# jQuery storing value from div in cookie and loading it when page is refreshed

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-cookie

I'm trying to store the value of this div when the button is clicked

```
<div id="results">
        <span id="eresult">0</span>
</div>

<input id="excellent" type="image" src="smile.png" name="image" width="150" height="150">
```

with the following

```
$('#excellent').click(function() {
    $("#voting").text("Thank you for rating!")
                .show()
                .delay(500)
                .fadeOut();

    var value = document.getElementById("eresult").innerHTML;
    var newValue = parseInt(value,10) + 1;
    document.getElementById("eresult").innerHTML = newValue;

    $.cookie('ename', newValue);
});
```

Am I right to store the cookie this way and how do I retrieve the value and display it in "eresult" again when the page is refreshed?

Comment: Do you use the jquery-cookie plugin?

Comment: Yup I've used it <script src="jquery.cookie.js"></script>

Comment: If you have too much trouble, you may want to consider localStorage as an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) you are setting the cookie the right way:

```
$.cookie('name', 'value');
```

You can read the cookie like this:

```
$.cookie('ename'); // => "value"
$.cookie('nothing'); // => undefined
```

You can set the content of `<span id="eresult">0</span>` like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#eresult').html(
        $.cookie('ename');
    );
});
```

Comment: I've been getting undefined in the "eresult" value until I tried your method of setting the content. However, as I click on the button to increment the value, after refreshing the page, it resets to 0 again instead of displaying the last number stored in the cookie. How do I ensure it displays the last stored value before the page refreshes

Comment: @user2728875 How are you developing this? This won't work in a sandbox environment, nor in *phonegap / cordova* applications.

Comment: It's just a html file running on the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the cookie with the name you created is present or not and after that you can print the value

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if($.cookie("ename") != '') {
        $("#eresult").html($.cookie("ename"));
         // or
        document.getElementById("eresult").innerHTML = $.cookie("ename");

    }
});
```

Comment: It does not seem to be present, does that mean the cookie was not stored correctly?

Comment: check alert(newValue); before creating cookies

Answer (score 0):

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $eresult = $('#eresult'),
            value = parseInt($eresult.text());  // Get value from #eresult

    if ($.cookie('ename')) {
        value = parseInt($.cookie('ename')); // Override value from cookie (if exists)
    }

    $eresult.text(value);

    $('#excellent').click(function() {
        $("#voting").text("Thank you for rating!")
            .show()
            .delay(500)
            .fadeOut();

        value += 1;                // Increase value...
        $.cookie('ename', value);   // ...and save it
        $eresult.text(value);       // show new value on page
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="results">
  <span id="eresult">0</span>
</div>

<input id="excellent" type="image" src="smile.png" name="image" width="150" height="150">
```

Comment: It does not seem to save the value as when the page refresh, the value becomes 0 again. May I know where the script should be placed? Before the end of the body tag or?

Comment: Value is saved when you click #excellent button. Script need to be placed after jQuery declaration and both should be placed just before body end tag.